# Android dialog ruins my main layout

Tags: android, layout, button, dialog

**Scenario:**
I have a main layout running.
Upon clicking on the "help" button a dialog appears
I dismiss the help dialog
The main screen has 2 buttons which are now broken (their graphics are wrong)

I am attaching the screenshot of the screen with the buttons which are now not complete (the bad buttons are "search contacts" and "call").

The question is obviously, how can I dismiss the dialog without affecting the graphics of the main screen?
[image: Screen with bad buttons after dialog disappears]

**The main screen layout**

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android           = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width    = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height   = "fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft     = "@dimen/general_logo_padding"
    android:paddingRight    = "@dimen/general_logo_padding"
    android:orientation     = "vertical"
    android:background      = "@drawable/login_background" >


        <!-- Logo -->
        <ImageView    
            android:id                  = "@+id/imgLogo"
            android:src                 = "@drawable/emobile_logo10"
            android:contentDescription  = "@string/login_imgdescriptor_logo"
            android:layout_width        = "fill_parent"
            android:layout_height       = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop    = "@dimen/callback_logo_margin"
            android:scaleType           = "fitStart" 
            android:layout_weight       = "0.1"/>


        <!-- Callback Fields -->
        <!-- Your Number -->
        <LinearLayout 
            xmlns:android               = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width        = "fill_parent"
            android:layout_height       = "wrap_content"
            android:orientation         = "horizontal" 
            android:layout_marginTop    = "@dimen/callback_yournumber_margin" 
            android:layout_weight       = "0.2">

            <TextView
                android:id              = "@+id/tvCBYournumber"
                android:layout_width    = "fill_parent"
                android:layout_height   = "wrap_content"
                android:text            = "@string/callback_btn_yournumber"
                android:textAppearance  = "?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize        = "@dimen/login_fields_text_size" 
                android:textColor       = "#F26A05" 
                android:layout_weight   = "6"/>

            <EditText 
                android:id                  = "@+id/etCBYourNumber"
                android:layout_height       = "wrap_content"
                android:layout_width        = "fill_parent"
                android:inputType           = "number"
                android:ellipsize           = "end"
                android:singleLine          = "true"
                android:minHeight           = "@dimen/edittext_min_height"
                android:background          = "@drawable/edittext_round_corners"        
                android:gravity             = "center"
                android:textAppearance      = "?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize            = "@dimen/login_fields_text_size" 
                android:layout_weight       = "4" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Connect To -->
        <LinearLayout 
            xmlns:android               = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width        = "fill_parent"
            android:layout_height       = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop    = "@dimen/callback_connectto_margin"
            android:orientation         = "horizontal" 
            android:layout_weight       = "0.2">

            <TextView
                android:id              = "@+id/tvCBConnectto"
                android:layout_width    = "fill_parent"
                android:layout_height   = "wrap_content"
                android:text            = "@string/callback_btn_connectto"
                android:textAppearance  = "?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize        = "@dimen/login_fields_text_size" 
                android:textColor       = "#F26A05" 
                android:layout_weight   = "6"/>

            <EditText 
                android:id                  = "@+id/etCBConnectTo"
                android:layout_height       = "wrap_content"
                android:layout_width        = "fill_parent"
                android:inputType           = "number"
                android:ellipsize           = "end"
                android:singleLine          = "true"
                android:minHeight           = "@dimen/edittext_min_height"
                android:background          = "@drawable/edittext_round_corners"        
                android:gravity             = "center"
                android:textAppearance      = "?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize            = "@dimen/login_fields_text_size" 
                android:layout_weight       = "4"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Line of Buttons -->
        <LinearLayout 
            xmlns:android               = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width        = "fill_parent"
            android:layout_height       = "wrap_content"
            android:orientation         = "horizontal" 
            android:layout_marginTop    = "@dimen/callback_button_margin" 
            android:minHeight           = "@dimen/callback_button_height"
            android:layout_weight       = "0.1">

            <Button
                android:id                  = "@+id/btnCBSearchContacts"
                android:layout_width        = "fill_parent"
                android:layout_height       = "fill_parent"
                android:text                = "@string/callback_btn_searchcontacts" 
                android:textSize            = "@dimen/login_fields_text_size" 
                android:drawableLeft        = "@android:drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar"
                android:layout_weight       = "1" />

            <Button
                android:id                  = "@+id/btnCBCall"
                android:layout_width        = "fill_parent"
                android:layout_height       = "fill_parent"
                android:text                = "@string/callback_btn_call" 
                android:layout_marginLeft   = "@dimen/callback_button_margin_betweenbuttons"
                android:textSize            = "@dimen/login_fields_text_size" 
                android:drawableLeft        = "@android:drawable/ic_menu_call"
                android:layout_weight       = "1" />

        </LinearLayout>                        

        <RelativeLayout 
            xmlns:android               = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width        = "fill_parent"
            android:layout_height       = "fill_parent" 
            android:layout_weight       = "3">

            <Button
                android:id                      = "@+id/btnCBHelp"
                android:layout_width            = "wrap_content"
                android:layout_height           = "wrap_content"
                android:padding                 = "@dimen/callback_button_help_padding"
                android:text                    = "@string/callback_btn_help" 
                android:layout_centerInParent   = "true"
                android:textSize                = "@dimen/login_fields_text_size" 
                android:drawableLeft            = "@android:drawable/ic_menu_help" />
        </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Dismissing a Dialog is not supposed to affect the Activity layout. You would have so show us some code for us to understand what might be going on.

Comment: show the appropriate xml file

Comment: ok I'll edit the question and add the xml layout - thanks

Comment: Hard to tell without code. Check that you do not change the layout in onResume of the activity.

Comment: I don't change GUI in the "onResume"

Comment: have you tried using a `LayoutInflater` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the problem.

It seems that the problem is with the library I use to create the buttons with, it is in very early Beta stages and for some reason causes this problem.

I am using Pixate library

I have now tweaked the code to use LayoutInflater (Parth Doshi's idea - thanks), and instead of extending Dialog I am now using an Alert dialog (Md Abdul Gafur), using these two methods decreases the problem but doesn't solve it.

Thank you all,
Chaiavi.

Answer (score 0):

Use AlertDialog to popup new layout and also see the android [documention](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html)

Thanks.

Comment: Won't help, I am extending "Dialog" and loading an XML (containing a relative layout and two text views inside)